# C++ lambda - move object after captured in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, move

I have this code:

```cpp
template<class Value>
inline void item_controller<Value>::middle_touch(item_value_view&)
{
    detail_item_controller<Value> detail;
    detail.value(value_);
    detail.return_function(
                          [&](bool ok)
                          {
                              if(ok)
                              {
                                  if(value() != detail.value())
                                  {
                                      view().edited(true);
                                      value(detail.value());
                                  }
                              }
                          });         

    gui::fsm->next(std::move(detail));
}
```

The problem is that the reference on `detail` captured in a lambda expression is invalid after moving object, is there any technique to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Or use `shared_ptr` ?